# phpexcel PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime not working

Tags: phpexcel

the file is xlsx and the column format is date MM-DD-YYYY

I have tried several different ways to determine if the value is a date.

PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime just is not working and do not know why. The data is being save in database and is showing the numbers as such:

41137
41618
42206
42076
41137
42206
41137
41988

my code:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fullFilePath);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fullFilePath);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$worksheetIndex = 1;
$worksheetName = '';
$actualRows = 0;

foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $lineNumber = 1;
    $worksheetName = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $columnSum = array();

    foreach($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row)
    {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set = true else set to false

        $columnNumber = 1;

        foreach($cellIterator as $cell)
        {

            $dataValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            //$dataValue = $cell->getFormattedValue();

            if(!empty($dataValue))
            {
                if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell))
                {
                    $dataValue = date('Y-m-d H', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($dataValue));
                }
                else
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: actually looking at the file in excel it shows the format is custom for the date field with format of mm-dd-yyyy.

Could this be the issue?

Comment: No, that won't be the issue, the function doesn't care whether the format is custom or one of the built-in formats.... `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime()` simply looks at the format mask for the cell (`mm-dd-yyyy` in this case), and returns true if it contains any of the characters `e`, `y`, `m`, `d`, `H` or `s`. It will fail if `setReadDataOnly()` is set to true, but shouldn't fail otherwise.

Comment: What file format is the call to `identify()` returning? What Reader is being used?

Comment: The returned format is Excel2007

Comment: Then can you let me know what version of PHPExcel is failing to identify dates, because I can't replicate this problem

Comment: It seems to be just this excel file, imported others without issue. Using version 1.8. Can send excel file if needed.

Comment: It might be useful to run some tests against the file if you can send it.... mark at lange dot demon dot co dot uk

Comment: Did you receive the file I sent?

Comment: I've received the file, and am looking at it now. Do you know how the file was created? Because it doesn't validate cleanly under Microsoft's Open XML SDK 2.0 productivity tool for MS Office under either 2007 or 2010 settings

Comment: No, I don't. Guess it could have been programmatically created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analysing the file, there's a few problems.... it doesn't validate cleanly under the Microsoft's Open XML SDK 2.0 productivity tool for MS Office.

Initial problem (which should trigger a loader error in PHPExcel) is the SheetView Zoom Scale, which should be a minimum value of 1. This problem can by "bypassed" by editing `Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/SheetView.php` and modifying the `setZoomScaleNormal()` method to avoid throwing the exception if the supplied argument value is out of range.

```
public function setZoomScaleNormal($pValue = 100)
{
    if (($pValue >= 1) || is_null($pValue)) {
        $this->zoomScaleNormal = $pValue;
//        } else {
//            throw new PHPExcel_Exception("Scale must be greater than or equal to 1.");
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The second problem is that custom number formats are defined with ids in the range 100-118, but all format ids below 164 are documented as reserved for Microsoft use. Excel itself is obviously more forgiving about breaking its documented rules.

You can resolved this by hacking the `Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php` file and modifying the `load()` method, around line 512, by commenting out the check that tells PHPExcel to use the built-in number formats:

```
//  if ((int)$xf["numFmtId"] < 164) {
//      $numFmt = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::builtInFormatCode((int)$xf["numFmtId"]);
//  }
```

or

```
if ((int)$xf["numFmtId"] < 164 &&
    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::builtInFormatCodeIndex((int)$xf["numFmtId"]) !== false) {
    $numFmt = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::builtInFormatCode((int)$xf["numFmtId"]);
}
```

There are also issues with font size definitions, but these won't prevent the file from loading

Comment: Thanks for your help, will give it a try and post back.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your time and help. Worked perfectly.